# Duplicate without user-selected canonical with Google Sites and custom domain

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-sites, google-selected-canonical

Got an issue with my Google Site for which I have registered a custom domain name (and Google, through the Search console, recognizes me as the owner).

The problem is that Google considers the canonical homepage to be the one with `sites.google.com/mywebsite` URL and not `example.com`

Since it's a Google Site, to my knowledge:

- I cannot change the `<head>` tag
- I cannot define a sitemap
- I cannot play with HTTP headers

Is there anyway that I declare `example.com` to be the canonical homepage instead of `sites.google.com/mywebsite`?

I've created an issue in [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/290951852), feel free to star it so their engineers can work on it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit the HTML or add code in any way to the pages, Google Sites don't allow it. The best thing that you can do is change all the internal links to the domain pages. It can be clunky because it causes some open in new windows (again can't add any code.) That may give Google a clue it needs to make the domain link the canonical one.

Answer (score 0):

Declare canonical elements in all your web pages.  If you don't have duplicates, declare them to point to themselves.  Even then its a suggestion to Google, it can chose to ignore it.  Syntax is

```
<link rel="canonical" href="mydomain.com">
```

or

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.boa-compress.fr">
```

These are declared in the `<head>` section. And declare them in `https://sites.google.com/view/boacompress` and `https://www.boa-compress.fr`.

Comment: https://www.boa-compress.fr and https://sites.google.com/view/boacompress are two URLs for the same site, a Google Site, in which it's not possible to add/change anything of the <head> section

Comment: Google sites only lets your create pages through a drag and drop GUI.  They don't give you any access to the source code of the pages.  There is no way to add link tags in their interface.